# Change the style of the header, footer and chapters

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm writing my thesis using `documentclass book`.
I want to change the header and footer of pages and modify slightly the size and position of chapter.

Now it looks more or less like this:
[image]
But I want something like this:
[image]

So what I want is:

1. Page numbers always centered at the bottom of pages
2. Headers in lowercase
3. Chapter number aligned to the left, not in bold and larger
4. Chapter title right aligned, in bold and size as it is now.

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nouppercase, swapnames]{frontespizio}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}



\newsavebox{\RGbox}
\newcommand{\R}[1]{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \sbox{\RGbox}{\colorbox{lightred}{\vphantom{fg}#1}}%
  \usebox{\RGbox}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\vrule width \wd\RGbox height .5ex depth -\dimexpr.5ex-0.4pt\relax}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\G}[1]{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \sbox{\RGbox}{\colorbox{lightgreen}{\vphantom{fg}#1}}%
  \usebox{\RGbox}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\vrule width \wd\RGbox height -\dimexpr\dp\RGbox-0.4pt\relax depth \dp\RGbox}%
  \endgroup
}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}


\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.95,.95,.95}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.8, 0.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.13, 0.55, 0.13}
\colorlet{lightgreen}{green!30}
\colorlet{lightred}{red!30}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Python,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  mathescape=<false>,
  tabsize=3
}

\lstnewenvironment{pseudocode}
  {\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Python,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  mathescape=<false>,
  tabsize=3
  }}
  {}
\lstnewenvironment{html}
  {\lstset{language=HTML,basicstyle={\ttfamily\small},frame=none, tabsize=3, numbers=none}}
  {}

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple,listofformat=subsimple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

I know it's a little messed up.. Sorry.

I read that I have to use the package **fancyhdr** but I'm just starting out with latex. Someone would know help me?

Thank you!

Comment: there are alternatives to `fancyhdr`, for example `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: Or `titletoc`, since you use `titlesec`.

Comment: @Bernard and how? I would not know where to start..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with  `titlesec` and `titleps` I translated you code for `\(sub)paragraph` in titlesec terms.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, italian, 11pt, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{fourier, cabin}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[nouppercase, swapnames]{frontespizio}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\SetTracking[no ligatures={f}]{encoding=*}{20}

 \titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]{\lsstyle}{\filright\Huge\chaptername\enspace \thechapter}{4ex}{\LARGE\bfseries\filleft}%
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{\lsstyle}{}{0pt}{\bfseries\LARGE\filleft}

\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}{1em}{}
\titleformat{name=\paragraph, numberless}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt} {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}{1em}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}{1em}{}
\titleformat{name=\subparagraph, numberless}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{\parindent} {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}{1em}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\sethead[][][\sffamily\small\chaptertitle]{\sffamily\small\sectiontitle}{}{}
\setfoot{}{\sffamily\thepage}{}
\headrule
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Titolo del primo capitolo}
\sffamily
\section{Una prima sezione}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]